# Convert ggplot to greyscale with stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an R package as a back-end engine for a GUI (JASP). I want to be able to have people convert their images to greyscale (for publication printing). For most plots, I can use `scale_colour_grey()`, but that doesn't work when colors are specified within stats_summary. For example:

```
# simulate data
set.seed(1212)
y = rnorm(100)
g = sample(c("a", "b"), 100, T)
d = data.frame(y=y, g=g)

### create ggplot
plot = ggplot(data=d, aes(x=g, y=y)) +
  geom_jitter() + 
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="point", size=3, color="red") +
  stat_summary(geom="errorbar", size=3, color="red") +
  theme_bw()

### converting to greyscale doesn't work
plot + scale_colour_grey()
```

After some research, I learned you can dissect the ggplot object then rebuilt it:

```
### can rebuilt ggplot object, but not ideal
q <- ggplot_build(plot)
q$data[[2]]$colour <- "black"
q$data[[3]]$colour <- "black"
q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
plot  = ggplotify::as.ggplot(q)
plot
```

That works fine, but I try to include as few dependencies in my R packages as possible. Do I really have to resort to another package (ggplotify) in order to modify the color coming from stat_summary?

A few notes: I don't want to have to modify the original stat_summary statement. Let's just pretend that cannot be modified. Also, let's assume I cannot add another package (aside from ggplot2, which is already loaded). Remember, I'm a "guest" in the JASP framework and I don't want to have to add another package to the list of packages they have to store.

Comment: Just remove `color = "red"` from `stat_summary` and put it in the initial call `ggplot(data=d, aes(x=g, y=y, color="red"))`. Like this the other layers (`geom_*` or `scale_*`) will inherit it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that's not an option. Again, I can't modify the existing plot. (And it wouldn't work in my case anyway...I don't want to modify the points color, just the color from stat_summary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually get at the ggplot object before it is built, reach into the layer that has the coloured object and change it. Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)

#  simulate data
set.seed(1212)
y = rnorm(100)
g = sample(c("a", "b"), 100, T)
d = data.frame(y=y, g=g)

### create ggplot
p <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=g, y=y)) +
  geom_jitter() + 
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="point", size=3, color="red") +
  stat_summary(geom="errorbar", size=3, color="red") +
  theme_bw()

p
```

[image]

```r
p$layers[[3]]$aes_params$colour <-  "gray50"

p
```

[image]

If you want a more general approach to change a particular geom's colour, you could do something like this function:

```r
recolour_geom <- function(gg_plot, geom, colour = "gray50")
{
  ss <- which(sapply(p$layers, function(l) {
                       paste(gsub("GEOM|GG|PROTO", "", toupper(class(l$geom))),
                       collapse = "")}) %in% toupper(geom))
  
  if (length(ss) > 0)
  {
    for (i in ss)
    {
      p$layers[[i]]$aes_params$colour <- colour
    }
  }
  p
}
```

Which allows you to do, for example

```r
recolour_geom(p, "errorbar", "blue")
recolour_geom(p, "point", "green")
```

[image]

Be aware though that this changes the ggplot by reference, so `p` is changed as a side effect of the function.

<sup>Created on 2020-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>